Python - Generator not working with next method
I created a generator to perform pagination on an api:
def page_helper(req, timeout=5, page=1, **kwargs):
    print(f"Page {page}", end="\r")
    try:
        response = req(params={**kwargs, "page": page})
        response = response.json()

    except Exception as e:
        status = response.status_code

        if status == "429":
            print(f"Rate limited. Waiting {timeout} seconds.")
            time.sleep(timeout)
            yield from page_helper(req, page=page, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise e

    else:
        if len(response) == kwargs["limit"]:
            yield from page_helper(req, page=page + 1, **kwargs)

        yield response


Later I use this generator somewhere like this
batches = page_helper(<some_request>, limit=100)


# get insert and updates per batch
for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
    print(f"Batch {i + 1}", end="\r")
    insert_batch = []
    update_batch = []

    # ... process batch


I want it to fetch each page as a batch and process it before it fetches the next batch. Fetching the batches works perfectly, but it keep on fetches pages without processing in between.
I tried to check the generator by calling next, and I expect it to only return one batch. However it starts the full iterations immediately:
next(batches) # --> Performs full iteration 
next(batches)
next(batches)
next(batches)

Is there something wring with my generator function?

Where are you actually using page_helper?

I changed it to make that more clear, but also found the fix

Why is len(response) == kwargs["limit"] the recursion criteria? Shouldn't there be a counter that eventually reaches limit?

The end is unknown, so with this statement I check whether the latest response equals the max number of results returned by the api. On the last page it will return less than the limit, so the recursion should end.

Why is your generator recursive to begin with? Just use a loop to do your pagination. If I've understood your intent correctly, this should do what you want:
def get_all_pages(request, retry_interval_seconds=5, start_page=1, **kwargs)
    current_page = start_page
    while True:
        try:
            response = request(params={**kwargs, "page": current_page})
            data = response.json()
        except Exception as error:
            if response.status_code == "429":
                time.sleep(retry_interval_seconds)
                continue # Try again without incrementing current_page
            else:
                raise error
        yield data
        if len(data) != kwargs["limit"]:
            break
        current_page += 1



In my head the recursion structure makes more sense as it kinda like "if x happens, run it again, if y happens, run again with these parameters", but I guess practically the while loop makes more sense as you do not run into the problem causing me to post this question. Thanks for the insight.

The iterator does not work because it yield from itself in the recursion, without actually yield something.
It is an easy fix by first yielding an item before yielding from the recursion:
def page_helper(req, timeout=5, page=1, **kwargs):
    print(f"Page {page}", end="\r")
    try:
        response = req(params={**kwargs, "page": page})
        response = response.json()

    except Exception as e:
        status = response.status_code

        if status == "429":
            print(f"Rate limited. Waiting {timeout} seconds.")
            time.sleep(timeout)
            yield from page_helper(req, page=page, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise e

    else:
        yield response  # --> moved before yielding from itself

        if len(response) == kwargs["limit"]:
            yield from page_helper(req, page=page + 1, **kwargs)
        


Don't you need to raise StopIteration when there are no more pages?

@Barmar Generators do that at the end automatically. If you do it manually, you even cause a RuntimeError.

@nocomment But when is the end? This code yields in all cases except error.

@Barmar For example at the bottom of the function. I'm confused... surely you know that?

Now I see it. When the last if fails it falls through and returns normally.

@Barmar That's for the deepest generator, yes. For all others it's after the if "succeeds" and all elements from their deeper generator have been yielded.

I understood the recursion, although I'm not sure it's the best way, rather than a loop (as in Paul M's answer).

@Barmar Yeah, I also thought a loop would be simpler. My guess is the OP found recursion simpler due to the two different paths of the two different recursive calls.

In my head the recursion structure makes more sense as it kinda like "if x happens, run it again, if y happens, run again with these parameters", but I guess the while loop makes more sense as you do not run into the problem causing me to post this question.
